# Python SimpleQueue not fair

Tags: python, queue, cython, python-multithreading

The Python standard library provides two implementations for the thread-safe `SimpleQueue`:

1. A [pure C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_queuemodule.c#L28-L35)
2. A fallback [Python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/queue.py#L258), IIUC in case Cython is not present (and because apparently [it's policy](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3346/files#r161618399) to also provide a pure Python implementation)

I was going through the code for both implementations in order to learn more. Among others, I learnt that the C implementation is reentrant while the Python one is not.

However, there's something that has left me quite confused, from [a comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/queue.py#L263-L266) in the code for the Python implementation:

> Note: while this pure Python version provides fairness
> (by using a threading.Semaphore which is itself fair, being based
> on threading.Condition), fairness is not part of the API contract.
> This allows the C version to use a different implementation.

How can a thread-safe, ["FIFO queue"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/queue.py#L259) not be fair? Isn't "fairness" guaranteed by definition, by it being FIFO in the first place?

Also, in what way does this "allow" the C version to use a different implementation? I find the wording quite confusing. Does it mean that somehow this is defined as a "potentially not fair FIFO queue", and that reflects in the C implementation? Or something else?

Comment: I don't think any of the standard library uses Cython. This looks to be a C implementation, not a Cython implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion arises from the distinction between thread safety and fairness in the context of queues.

Thread safety ensures that concurrent access to shared data structures, like a queue, does not lead to data corruption or unexpected behavior. In the case of a FIFO queue, thread safety ensures that multiple threads can enqueue and dequeue items without causing issues such as race conditions or corrupting the queue's internal state.

Fairness, on the other hand, refers to the order in which threads get access to a shared resource. A fair queue ensures that threads obtain access to the queue in a certain order (such as first-come, first-served), which might be different from simple FIFO ordering. Fairness doesn't guarantee thread safety; it's about the scheduling or ordering of threads accessing the shared resource.

Regarding the comment you mentioned in the Python implementation of `SimpleQueue`, it's highlighting that although the Python version uses a fair mechanism (a `threading.Semaphore` based on `threading.Condition`), fairness in the queue's behavior is not a documented part of the API contract. In essence, while fairness might be observed due to the implementation details (using a fair semaphore), the Python standard library doesn't guarantee fairness as part of the official behavior for `SimpleQueue`.

The comment about allowing the C version to use a different implementation means that since fairness is not a guaranteed part of the API contract, the C implementation of `SimpleQueue` might choose to use a different approach that sacrifices fairness in favor of other optimizations or requirements. It implies that the C version could potentially use a different internal mechanism for thread safety without adhering strictly to a fair ordering of threads accessing the queue.

In summary, the confusion might stem from the distinction between thread safety (ensuring no corruption of shared data structures) and fairness (ensuring a specific order of thread access). While a FIFO queue is inherently ordered, it doesn't guarantee fairness in terms of thread scheduling, and the Python implementation's fairness isn't a guaranteed part of the API contract, allowing flexibility for different implementations to prioritize other aspects like performance or resource utilization.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So is the C implementation fair, aside from fairness not being specified by its contract?

Comment: @LuigiD. I think this answer is just a copy-paste from ChatGPT (although it looks broadly right). So I wouldn't expect the answerer to be able to usefully follow up about the C implementation.